# Controller action not executing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Environment:

```
Rails: 3.2.12
Ruby: ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16 revision 34643) [x86_64-linux]
```

In my routes.rb, I have:

```
 match '/attendance', to: "attendance#attendance_dashboard"
```

In my attendance_controller.rb, I have:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!
before_filter :allow_only_if_admin

def attendance_dashboard
  logger.info("File: #{__FILE__} -- Line: #{__LINE__}")
  @registered_and_not_checked_in = get_registered_and_not_checked_in()
end
```

I am running on the test system, so logger.info should write to the test.log file.

When I run the /attendance action, I get 500 error, and here's what I see in the test.log file:

```
Started GET "/attendance" for 73.169.212.94 at 2015-02-06 15:11:06 +000
Processing by AttendanceController#attendance_dashboard as HTML
[1m[35mUser Load (0.4ms)[0m  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 215ms
```

I was expecting to have the logger info requested logged to the test.log file, but it's not there, so I'm failing prior to that. Any ideas?

## Solution:

The issue was not with the code, it was that user #2, who is signed in as an admin, has a JSON record in his DB record that was failing to unpack properly. Once that was fixed the issue went away.

Comment: One of your `before_filters` is throwing an error. Is there a `User` with `id` of 2? If not, `User.find(2)` will cause an error and nothing will be logged.

Comment: There is a user 2, so that's not the problem

Comment: Your stack trace should point you to the specific line with the problem.  Like @ptd i suspect it is one of the before filters rather than the actual action.

Comment: Have you tried commenting out the filters?

Comment: Commenting out the filters took care of the problem. This is strange because I am using these filters in a couple of other controller and they work fine, so they're well tested. I am wondering if there is some issue with data corruption in the DB for user #2

Comment: then provide whole controller and application controller code

Comment: ptd: if you answer this question, I will credit you with the solution